# Separating the scraped result of an active webpage in an array using python

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the stock data but even though I'm using the "find elements by id" the result is one text.
i have tried various methods such as find elements by xpath and etc..
and i tried to make an array that contains all the IDs by finding "attribute 'target'" so i can loop through it but i wasn't successful so i had to code each ID.

```
import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


url = 'http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15131F'
delay = 100

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, delay)

zapna = driver.find_elements_by_id(id_='43479730079120887')
renik = driver.find_elements_by_id(id_='33854964748757477')
retko = driver.find_elements_by_id(id_='3823243780502959')
rampna = driver.find_elements_by_id(id_='67126881188552864')
mafakher = driver.find_elements_by_id(id_='4247709727327181')

for ii in retko:
    print(ii.text , "\n")

driver.close()
```

and the result is:

```
رتكوكنترل‌خوردگي‌تكين‌كو2,1512.531M63.044 B25,14523,88824,900-245-0.9724,907-238-0.9523,88825,699-749-33.2512,55324,90024,9035,4601
```

what i expect is:

```
رتكو
كنترل‌خوردگي‌تكين‌كو
2,151
2.531M
63.044 B
25,145
23,888
24,900
-245
-0.97
24,907
-238
-0.95
23,888
25,699
-749
-33.25
1
2,553
24,900
24,903
5,460
1
```

any idea ?

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i need the result to be separated as i mentioned but they are sticked together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to go one layer deeper (using, for example, xpath) and iterate through the children:

```
for ii in retko:
    targets = ii.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*')
    for target in targets:
        print(target.text)
```

Output:

```
رتكو
رتكو
كنترل‌خوردگي‌تكين‌كو
كنترل‌خوردگي‌تكين‌كو
3,149
3.235M
3.235M
```

etc.

Comment: it worked ! just had to delete some repeated data. like the sign and name, etc..Thank you